# Android, I have no idea how to stop this sound loop

Tags: android, audio

As the title suggest, I have problems with the sound loop as I have no idea how to break the loop. When the loop is running, I can't control the volume of the device.

```
public void onClick(View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();
                if (on){
                     boolean is = true;
                     android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO);
                     int buffersize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(20000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
                     AudioRecord arec = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, 20000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, buffersize);
                     AudioTrack atrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 20000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, buffersize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
                     atrack.setPlaybackRate(20000);
                     byte[] buffer = new byte[buffersize];
                     arec.startRecording();
                     atrack.play();
                     while(is){
                         arec.read(buffer, 0, buffersize);
                         atrack.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                     }
                     arec.stop();
                        atrack.stop();
                        is = false;
                           }
                           }});

        }
```

Comment: Put that code in AsyncTask or something similiar which runs on background. Also your while is infinite because you are not breaking or setting `is` to false in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AudioTrack.stop()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html) or `AudioTrack.pause()`

Answer (score 0):

Well... you are setting the boolean "is = true" at first. And then you have the while-loop " while (is) " that is an infinite loop because "is" will always be true, and never goes at the line wehere you set it "false". What do you want to do in the while-loop ?

Comment: The while loop is to keep the recording going and continuously reading the data and projecting it out of the speaker.

Comment: Yes but the main thread will be stuck in that while. That is a infinite loop, you will not get out of there.

Answer (score 0):

use `arec.release()`; and `atrack.release()` instead of `arec.stop();` and `atrack.stop`
this might help you, good luck... : )

Comment: My togglebutton stays highlighted and I cant control the system volume in the app :(. The sound doesn't turn off too.